# Remove gaps in a plot when plotting weekwise yealy data when the weekyear is numeric

Tags: r, plot, week-number

I am plotting price changes week-wise with the x-axis in the format "201301" where 2013 is the year and 01 is the week. I get gaps between the years after week 52 i.e. "201352" to "201399" since it is in an integer format. How do I remove the gaps?

Following is the data I am using at [docs.google.com](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zqutU5QpbJ4DTv4wATBdqmjYyScdgJ80eYzznos5lo/edit?usp=sharing)

```
df <- read.table(text="Year_week    Price
201301  1769
201302  1764
201303  1764
201304  1762.56
201305  1775
201306  1776
201307  1775
201308  1800
201309  1827
201310  1846
201311  1848
201312  1837.5
201313  1862
201314  1862.5
201315  1862
201316  1863
201317  1862
201318  1872
201319  1900
201320  1920
201321  1914
201322  1900
201323  1890
201324  1896
201325  1898
201326  1884
201327  1872
201328  1872
201329  1869
201330  1850
201331  1836
201332  1840
201333  1848
201334  1850
201335  1863
201336  1869
201337  1860
201338  1862
201339  1869
201340  1859
201341  1850
201342  1870
201343  1875
201344  1875
201345  1881
201346  1870
201347  1887.5
201348  1870
201349  1879.5
201350  1886
201351  1872.78
201352  1914
201401  1958
201402  1962
201403  1958
201404  1955
201405  1960.98
201406  1989.5
201407  2021.882
201408  2016
201409  1999.2
201410  1987.5
201411  1992
201412  2033.5
201413  2054
201414  2050
201415  2028.6
201416  2040
201417  2028.6
201418  2024
201419  2002
201420  2000
201421  1998.81
201422  2000
201423  2002
201424  2010.96
201425  1999.2
201426  1995",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you tell what kind of plot you are using, e.g. barplot or lineplot and give your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert numeric to factor.

```
plot(as.factor(df$Year_week),df$Price)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Another way is to keep date in date format, this way plot will behave as expected. We need to convert `YYYYWW` to `YYYY-MM-DD` using `ISOweek` package then plot.

```
library(ISOweek)
library(ggplot2)

#convert numeric to date - YYYYWW to YYYY-MM-DD
df$Year_week_clean <- ISOweek2date(
  paste0(substr(df$Year_week,1,4),"-W",
         substr(df$Year_week,5,7),"-1")
  )

#plot original
ggplot(data=df, aes(Year_week,Price)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("YYYYWW")

#plot clean
ggplot(data=df, aes(Year_week_clean,Price)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

[image]
[image]